# Changing a proprety inside a rails model just for the views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a little problem. I found it really hard to create a title for this, I hope I can explain it better:

One of our clients demanded that in every instance of "item_number", when it's from the Product model, the app will have to show it with 5 leading zeroes.

The "item_number" proprety in that model is in fact an integer on the database.

Our first approach would be just change in the model the value:

```
def item_number
  item_number.to_s.rjust(5, '0')
end
```

Of course we get a:

```
SystemStackError at /
stack level too deep
```

And I'm pretty sure this will mess up when creating/updating records, but it doesn't matter, it doesn't work anyways.

The solution would be simple, just create:

```
def item_number_with_leading_zeroes
  item_number.to_s.rjust(5, '0')
end
```

And replace item_number with it on our views.

But, we have over 5.000 usages of this, and some of them were not from this model (and we only need to replace the item_number on this model) and some of them are inside Iterators that we coded not using the parent object name (so I may not know if it's from this model or not), others are from custom form inputs, we can't just "replace all".

I would have to manually check every single instance of "item_number" and see if it's needed to change it to that new method or not. And I can still make mistakes and impact a lot of stuff.

I only need to change it on the views, I thought about a way to get it working with the helpers but that would still mean I would have to change it case-by-case.

There is another option to fix it, updating all records on the database to string with the zeroes and making a before_save option from now on, but we would like a rails solution first, before going that way (leaving the DB as is right now).

I'm out of ideas, I don't know if there is a solution, I thought about asking here first hoping someone can share some thought.
Is there any way I can do this without having to manually check the whole application?

Ruby 2, Rails 4.0

Thank you!

Comment: "one of our clients demanded" - what about your other clients? Also, is this field readonly? It seems to me that changing the type (int -> string) is generally not a very good idea. I would go with presenters or helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `read_attribute` to avoid the recursion:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def item_number
    read_attribute(:item_number).to_s.rjust(5, '0')
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but that didn't work. I tryed using alias_attribute instead of create_alias (undefined method `create_alias' for #<Class:0x0000000cb9ebd0>)

I also tryed changing the methods, changing their order on alias_attribute, I tryed changing a few other things... I would either get stack level too deep or blank values...

Comment: @HelioBorges I updated my answer. The `alias_attribute` mechanism doesn't "block" the original attribute accessors.

Comment: All right, that seems to do the trick, I can't believe it!! Checking right now if it bugs anything else, but I think this is it... Thank you very much!!